# How to change the scroll bar color in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, scrollbar

Please tell me any one How can i change the scroll bar color in windows phone 7 and also i want to customize the scroll bar in windows phone 7.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the "background property in your xaml code where the scroll bar lies?

try this:

```
<ScrollBar Background="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="299,144,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

don't use this whole thing what i want you to take from it is you should have a line of xaml code similar to this just enter the background property as i did. hope this is more clear.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply, actually it's not working. i have stack panel and text block content also within scroll viewer my code is

Comment: i had put it your sample code at inside of stack panel of scroll viewer, is there another way to execute? pls tell me

Comment: have you figured this out yet @siva?

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy with coding it into XAML, find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6300264/1943075). Or else the shortest and the easiest way is to use **Expression Blend**.

Also a snippet I found elsewhere:

```
<ListBox x:Name="myListBox">
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ScrollViewer">
    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ScrollStates">
                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="00:00:00.5"/>
                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualState x:Name="Scrolling">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalScrollBar"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalScrollBar"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="NotScrolling"/>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Grid Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
            <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="ScrollContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
            <ScrollBar x:Name="VerticalScrollBar" Background="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="Auto" IsHitTestVisible="False" IsTabStop="False" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" Minimum="0" Opacity="0" Orientation="Vertical" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="5"/>
            <ScrollBar x:Name="HorizontalScrollBar" Background="Blue"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="5" IsHitTestVisible="False" IsTabStop="False" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" Minimum="0" Opacity="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Hope all this helps you :)