# Vertical Scrollbar not visible in listbox inside popup-element

Tags: xaml, listbox, popup, windows-phone-8.1

The vertical Scrollbar is visible in W 8.1 but not in WP 8.1 on my emulator.

What have i missed?

I have also tried to set VerticalScrollBarVisibility to Visible

```
<Popup x:Name="LayerPopupWindow" IsLightDismissEnabled="True" >
<ListBox x:Name="MyList" Margin="3" Width="auto" Background="#DDFFFFFF"
Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight,ElementName=MyMapView}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="auto" >
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsVisible, Mode=TwoWay}" BorderBrush="Black" MinWidth="30"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ID, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
<ToolTipService.ToolTip>
<StackPanel MaxWidth="400">
<TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding CopyrightText}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
</StackPanel>
</ToolTipService.ToolTip>
</TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
</Popup>
```

Comment: Check following solutions: http://ctrlf5.net/?p=252 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300166/changing-scroll-bars-color-of-a-listbox-on-windows-phone-7 > normally you need to change the style of the scrollbar inside the listbox through templating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looked at your links Depechie and tried it in my example, for some reason the scrollbars still wasnt visible.

Then i found this link
[Making ScrollViewer's ScrollBar always visible through overriding or styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25058049/making-scrollviewers-scrollbar-always-visible-through-overriding-or-styling)

Tried it and the scrollbars know were visible, so problem solved.